# High elevation non- pv Burnham boiler with Tejurland powerventer installed at sea level

Tags: hvac, heating, boiler, natural-gas, venting

I have a 203ncl-tei2 boiler installed in danvers Massachusetts. This town is at sea level, not 2000k miles up. This boiler also has a failed tejurland (universal control) powerventer motor on it that is only humming, not spinning. I Looked for a dead animal, or nest that would stop the squirrel cage connected to the motor from spinning freely and it was clear. Ontop of the boiler we have a factory automatic damper assy. Johnson controls or similar. I call burnham and ask what the original power venter model number is and they tell me what some pros may already know, (i didnt), that the tei2 in the model number is actually (t)taco, (el)elevation, (2) 2 is 2,000 ft

.Note:he was not.100% sure about the el. He was definetly sure PV would be in the model number and it was not tejurland. There is no chimney on this house, never was. The Power venter wall thimble outside is very old definetly older than the 1 year old motor that failed. Burnham also said this is not a boiler that can be converted to a powerventer which is something i do not understand because he said if it does not have pv in the model number it should not have one. Period. I am not questioning Burnham they help me out on a regular basis but no one is perfect. I have in the past converted a boiler with a factory reccomended power venter after a customer lost the chimney. I called burnham and got lucky they had an option for that specific boiler i was working on that day. i also remember seeing it in the install manual as an addendum or seperate manual, but i am not 100% sure if it was burnham or U.S. Boiler.

Is this a fact with U.S. Boiler?

Anyone have experience with this?

What are the ramifications of an elevated boiler installed at sea level? Other than it taking longer to produce heat? , burnham said the elevation was not a big deal as its been working fine for almost 20   years.

If i can not find another awnser, i will have to tell the customer they need a new boiler or i will have to walk away. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello, again. Please don't double-post; edit your original question with whatever new information you can supply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you need repair help or a help deciding how to deal with the situation. Any burner, be it oil, propane or whatever at high elevation needs to be derated. So for gas, smaller orfus sizes. So if the boiler was designed for 2000 foot elevation it should be under firing at sea level. But in this case with your 203ncl-tei2 it's up to 2000 feet elevation most gas burners are factory 0-2000 feet from the factory including this one.

Boiler information 
[image]
Www.ecomfort.com

The guys at Burnham are telling you that it is not approved for power vent. That just means that it was not tested for the application, which means it's not to code, no matter what. That also means you are liable for any harm or damage if you are aware of the issue. That doesn't explicitly exclude a aftermarket add-on power ventor. The aftermarket manufacturer can give approval for the specific model and assume liability, but you would need documentation. If I'm ever in that situation I will inform the customer and depending on my gut feel about them (or how well I know them) I will red tag it and give them a couple of options for replacement or do the repair and tell them that I was never there. I would only do the latter if I really know them well and I'm confident that it's safe. So basically, tag it. If the motor is humming and has the right voltage and the cap (if equiped) is good it's the motor. But I wouldn't change it. I'm in Canada and our codes for HVAC are more strict than in the US so it's hard for me to say to you that you should decommission the unit in the middle of winter but if the s*** hits the fan you don't want to be holding the bag.